# Issue with function that processes doubles into time

Tags: java

I created a method that processed a double so that it turned the double into a 'duration' (Ex. The input 3.89 would equal 4.29 like 4 minutes and 29 seconds). My issue is that when I enter any double that has the decimal value .59, my input becomes infinitely looped, meaning I can input an infinite amount of times and nothing will happen.

This is for an online course on Java I'm taking, I've been tasked to create a playlist-like a program (very simple, scanners).

```
Song newSong = new Song(songName, scannerDouble);
```

```
public Song(String title, double duration) {
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = doubleToDuration(duration);
}


    private static double doubleToDuration(double duration) {
        duration = Math.round(duration * 100.0) / 100.0;

        double countTillHundred = 0;
        for(@SuppressWarnings("unused")
        double i = .01; countTillHundred + (Math.round((duration % 1) * 100.0) / 100.0) < 1; i+=.01) {
            countTillHundred+=.01;
        }
        double durationDecimal = 1 - (Math.round(countTillHundred * 100.0) / 100.0);

        while(true) {
            if(durationDecimal > .59) {
                double addTimesIn = Math.floor(durationDecimal / .60);
                double addTime = durationDecimal %= .60;
                duration = Math.floor(duration / 1) + addTimesIn + addTime;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return duration;
    }
```

So the result of the method is correct actually (i tested it with sysout's) but for some reason, it still causes the loop. And I know it's the method because I took out the method from the constructor and it worked fine. Thank you so much to all who can help me!

Comment: Read this: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic
or
Why don’t my numbers add up?](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 2):

As a guess for why your code is getting stuck, it may be due to the %= operator being used on doubles. The % (modulus) operator can only be used on integers, as it returns the remainder following integer division. It doesn't work on doubles, because you'd have a decimal returned instead of a integer.

Here's a version of your code that I believe to be simplified and some critiques.

```
double convertToDuration(double time) // using time instead of duration, because it's not the duration yet
{
  double minutes = Math.floor(time); // returns the part in front of the decimal
  double seconds = time - minutes; // returns the decimal

  while (seconds > .59) 
  {
    minutes += 1;
    seconds -= .60;
  }

  return minutes + seconds;
}
```

As criticism, I have a couple suggestions to improve as you go forward. First is to use more descriptive variable names. `addTimesIn` and `addTimes` don't mean much to me. Also, with a name like `doubleToDuration`, it doesn't make sense to pass in `duration` since that is what it sounds you will be returning.

Second, personally, I dislike using `while(true)` loops. That's just personal style, but in your case where you have an `if` and a `else` with a `break;` statement, it makes more sense to use a specific condition inside the while loop.

```
// good
while (seconds > .59) 
{
  minutes += 1;
  seconds -= .60;
}

// not as good
while(true)
{
  if(seconds > .59)
  {
    minutes += 1;
    seconds -= .60;
  }
  else
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

I know I don't know the problem explicitly, but I don't know why you have the `countTillHundred` and that clunky looking `for` loop. If it's just for the conversion, I don't see where you would need that.

The first line doesn't make sense to me either. The only reason I could see needing that is if you have time passed in with more than 2 decimal points of precision. Maybe have some form of input check before going into the function.

This function should just run conversions, it shouldn't also be responsible for cleaning up inputs, counting to 100, AND converting.

Sorry if any of this seemed too harsh. Best of luck going forward in your course!

Comment: Thanks so much for this updated code! I'm sorry you had to spoon feed me it but the issue is resolved!

I'm sure you were right about the operand situation, I actually never knew that it didn't work on doubles. In all honesty, I found the code I used for my method on Stack Overflow and altered it to fit what I needed. I knew it was clunky however once you cleaned it up I couldn't believe how little code could have been used!

I'll take your advice about the while(true) also, as it seems you have more experience than me. Also, don't be sorry, thank you for your critiquing!

Comment: @ Dylan Perez- Please upvote (if you haven't already) and "accept" Carson's answer.  And please do read this link: https://floating-point-gui.de/